# Vuetify default button with Icon and change color when toggle

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to Vuetify and Vue.js and I am trying I have two buttons that make api calls with two different routes.  Thats working, however, I need a way to set the default button to a certain color along with like a check mark.  Then, set the same when the other button is clicked.  [image]

When page I am trying to set the New Patient to a certain color along with a check icon.  Then when Recall Patient is selected, to switch that same color with the same Icon.

Here is my code:

```
 <v-row justify="space-around">
                      <v-btn
                        @click="fortyFive"
                        rounded
                      >
                      New Patient
                      </v-btn>
                      <v-btn
                        @click="seventyFive"
                        rounded
                      >
                        Recall Patient
                      </v-btn>
              </v-row>
```

onClick

```
seventyFive () {
  this.fetchData75()
},
fortyFive () {
  this.fetchData45()
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there are some `vuejs` basics that we should use here.

- First a property which will set the current selected button identifier.
- Based on that data property we can use `v-if` to change the color or icon whatever we want.

```
// define selectedButton property
data: function () {
    return {
      selectedButton: null,
    }
  },
```

Now on click of button set this property. I'm picking `75` or `45` based on your naming conventions. You can choose whatever you want.

```
seventyFive () {
  this.selectedButton = 75;
  this.fetchData75()
},
fortyFive () {
  this.selectedButton = 45;
  this.fetchData45()
},
```

To make a button containing color and an icon. Vuetify syntax is

```
<v-btn rounded color="primary">
   Primary
   <v-icon dark>mdi-check</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Now modify your template to change color for the same based on value of `selectedButton`

```
<v-btn @click="fortyFive" rounded :color="selectedButton == 45 ? 'primary' : ''">
   New Patient
   <v-icon dark v-if="selectedButton == 45">mdi-check</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<v-btn @click="seventyFive" rounded :color="selectedButton == 75 ? 'primary' : ''">
   Recall Patient
   <v-icon dark v-if="selectedButton == 75">mdi-check</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```